# Run Groovy Scripts in IntelliJ fails

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I can't run or debug Groovy scripts in IntelliJ. I'm getting the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter`. Running scripts from cmd works propertly (I'm using groovyc and groovy command).

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
import org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree
import org.w3c.dom.Document

// load the PDF file using PDFBox
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new java.io.File("file.pdf"))
// create the DOM parser
PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree()
// parse the file and get the DOM Document
Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf)
```

Comment: groovy libraries are not in classpath

Comment: how to add groovy libraries into classpath?

Comment: See simple answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450683/errorcannot-compile-groovy-files-no-groovy-library-is-defined-for-module-mypr It worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12 depedency in my pom.xml file. Bug is resolved. Thanks All for your hints :)

Answer (score 3):

Create `Run Configuration` (⌘N), and set the `Module` to the Module that contains all of your dependencies.

[image: See image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you describe your thought in more details?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/lyzFK

What should I do there ? The script fails even if I don't use my own class.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I don't have stacktrace in Run console. I have only this text:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" ...
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I had had the same problem until I did the next:

1. deleted the groovy from "Global Libraries" (Don't forget to click the 'Apply' button
   [screenshot how to delete groovy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj7HJ.png)
2. Opened any groovy file, and click on "Configure Groovy SDK"
   [screenshot how to select groovy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM02V.png)
3. Selected the folder with groovy installation (see on the screenshot above)

After all, I can run/debug my scripts from IDEA

Comment: That worked for me as a blessing. Basically following your steps I have reconfigured the same global library for the Groovy. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create you script not as Groovy class.
Use this way:

```
Ctrl + Shift + A  -> Groovy Script  -> Set script name
```

Comment: I have Groovy script but inside I have class and some code after the class.

Comment: I think you should create class in separate file

Comment: I moved class to separate file and I still have the same problem: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter".

Comment: I don't think that code is the cause because every script fails with this error.