# Add Lombok plugin to IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Intellij doesn't recognize Spring annotations and I think its connected to Lombok.

I added the plugin in IntelliJ settings and enabled annotation processing

I am using maven and I have this dependency

```
dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Still Intellij can't recognize Slf4j and Spring annotations

Comment: Have you included Spring dependencies? Spring annotations have nothing to do with Lombok

Comment: Please show us your pom.xml. I think that the problem you are facing is not related with Lombok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps
1. Build spring application as mentioned in: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

2. Install Lombok in IntelliJ (check [compatibility](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) with your version of IntelliJ idea)

[image: lombok installation]

3. Add as a dependency in (pom.xml/build.gradle/other build files)

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>    <scope>provided</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

4. Build project
5. Enable annotation processing in IntelliJ(You have to do this every time you import new project, if you want it to be enabled by default then follow steps mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44457133/2987755) SO OP.
   `File` | `Other Settings` | `Default Settings`, navigate to the compiler settings, annotation processing and enable this option before importing the project.

If you still face issue do once `File`/`Invalidate caches`/`Invalidate and restart`

[image: annotation Processor]

That's it.

Comment: I have done all the steps above. Only I haven't tried to actually build the project. After I try to build I get "cannot compile groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module exampleModule" .. maybe I need to see how to resolve this one first. I had to delete project and import again that's why I am having these difficulties

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43450889/2987755 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275395/2987755 should help with groovy error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the lombok plugin to intellij as well.

```
Files->Settings->Plugins->Click on Browse repositories->Search for Lombok->Install plugin->Restart Intellij
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to preferences in Intellij and install Lombok Plugin.Then it will work