# IntelliJ not recognising Lombok methods but compiles successfully

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using Lombok version 1.16.16, with Lombok plugin 0.23-2018.3 & IntelliJ IDEA 183.4886.37. I've used Lombok in a personal project where everything works as it should. I recently cloned a work repository which is a project with many about half a dozen sub-modules, each with their own `pom.xml` and `*.iml` file. My colleague does not have any issues.

When I open a class which is annotated with `@Slf4j`, I see this in all methods of my logger:

[image]

The application compiles fine and when I hit that method it logs successfully to the console. Annotation processing is enabled, also. This is fine but it's very inconvenient not being able to use IntelliSense.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54006000/2987755

Comment: Have u tried adding it your classpath? Alt + Enter, Add to classpath.        It could be that the lombok plugin is in your project, just intellij doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be IntelliJ being a prima donna. Invalidating my caches and restarting fixed the issue.

`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`