# Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

After an update of android studio and gradle, I can not compile (in release mode) my application anymore.When I try to generate the APK, I receive this error:

> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
>       file:/Users/antonioleva/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
>       https://maven.google.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
>       https://maven.google.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
>   Required by:
>       project : > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.3

This is my gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-fragment'
        exclude module: 'internal_impl-23.0.1'


    }
    implementation('com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-fragment'
        exclude module: 'internal_impl-23.0.1'
    }


    implementation('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'internal_impl-23.0.1'
        exclude module: 'support-fragment'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '...'
    }



    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Worked fine for me

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
    ...
}
...
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, everything was correctly installed but not found; I also refreshed everything that was refreshable in IntelliJ; I removed all the temporary folders in the project. Everything was useless.

Then I solved the problem like that, from terminal:

```
gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
```

This solved the issue.

In extremis, you can delete the content of the global cache folder used by gradle (it was not necessary in my case); for example could be this:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches
```

*Mi esperas, ke tio helpos iun, ĉar mi perdis multe da tempo.*