# Could not download groovy-all.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15) in Android Studio 3.3 Beta 2

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

**The Problem:**

when i am trying to build **release variant** of my **Kotlin** project in **Android Studio 3.3 Beta 2**, it is getting stuck randomly for 10 to 16 minutes after spitting some errors.

Running `gradle/assemble` it showed following errors :

```
> Task :app:lintVitalRelease FAILED
:app:lintVitalRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 8 mins 23.222 secs.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download groovy-all.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
         > Connection reset

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
```

**What I've tried so far**

- Answer from this question [Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763121/could-not-find-org-codehaus-groovygroovy-all2-4-12)
  but it isn't downloading at all and getting stuck.
  [image: status bar while trying to build]
- tried to open the link in the browser and it is downloading the file but it is not downloading while in the build process https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar
- created a brand new project tried to release it same problem there

**Project Gradle settings**

```
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official


classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha02'
//workaround for Dagger2 > 2.16
classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'
```

i don't know what is causing it to stop downloading or not allowing it to download the groovy file but i am stuck here and can't release my app :(

Comment: Does it happen on stable 3.2?

Comment: no i am unable to release anything from there too , it is stuck there too in new project , it's been more then 10 minutes.

Comment: Are you using a proxy, or do you have slow internet? Does a different version of Groovy work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by waiting for 30 minutes so it can download the groovy jar file, before trying it for 2 hours and it was no problem with my internet.

thanks @TheWanderer to hint me about the internet

Comment: The problem should be unstable of jcenter, or maybe it simply rejects the request in your build environment, because your build environment requests too often.

Answer (score 7):

when i updated my **Android Studio** to **ver3.3** today ,i met this problem ,and here are  my errors:

```
"Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease"....    
"org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath"
```

.....

```
"Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)"
```

.....

```
"org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'."
```

.....

```
"org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'"
```

.....

this time its '**junit.jar**',and 30mins ago its '**groovy-all.jar**'....ithink there are sth wrong with my internet,so i have tried many times and waited for hours...

but when i searched '***Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease***' when i was waiting ,i found another solution,add the following lines to **android{}** in **app\build.gradle**

```
"lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}"
```

i dont know why,but it works,the red lines disappear...

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is right, just one more thing. For me I was using VPN as I was connected to database via secure channel. Hence, when I was running android studio, it was failing at similar point. Once I turned off my vpn and ran again it worked like a charm...